# How to modify dft function in opencv?

Tags: opencv, dft

I need to modify some of the variables inside the dft function in OpenCV to make it suitable for my application.

1. Where can I find the dft source code?
   I've tried `C:\opencv243\build\include\opencv2\core.hpp` but it only gives me the description of dft:

> //! performs forward or inverse 1D or 2D Discrete Fourier Transformation
>   CV_EXPORTS_W void dft(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int flags=0, int nonzeroRows=0);
>
> What is the procedure after source code modification? Do I have to give it a different name such as `dft2()`?
>
> Where to save the new function?
>
> I'm using visual Studio 2010 and OpenCV 2.4.3 installed on windows7 (32 bit).
>   Please note that I'm new to OpenCV and just switched from MATLAB. Therefore if you are willing to help, I would be grateful if you could explain clearly.

In MATLAB I could simply right-click on the function and see the source file (for the open source functions only).

Thanks

Payam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. DFT function can be found in the dxt.cpp source file. This is located in $opencv2.3$\opencv\modules\core\src
2. If you save it as the same function you will *Overwrite* that function and wont be able to use the original function. If you only want your new function then just change the code, if you want the original functionality save it as something else, dft2 would surfice but i suggest saving it as something more meaningfull like dft"whathaveIdone"
3. Either create some new files etc or just save it as a new function with dxt.cpp, you will need to create function definitions etc
4. In order to find this information I opened the OpenCV solution in Visual Studio and did a solution wide search for DFT

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick and flawless reply. I just did not understand the last sentence "just save it as a new function with dxt.cpp". Can I do the modification and save the modified version as dft"whathaveIdone".cpp in the same directory as dxt.cpp and then in my OpenCV program say dft"whathaveIdone"() to call the function?

Comment: Yes you can save it in dxt.cpp however you wont be able to call it without putting the correct function definitions in dxt.hpp or whatever headerfile you use to connect your code (file) with dxt.cpp

I would suggest reading [this](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/713133-callling-function-another-file) and creating a new question with the c++ tag if you need any more help. G./

Comment: Just for the future reference, how do we find location of such functions, in general. In other words, how did you find out that the location of dft function is in $opencv2.3$\opencv\modules\core\src\dxt.cpp?